# How to access the User object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm using discord.js for my bot, and I want to use [the User object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) to get the ID from that. However, the docs aren't very specific on how to use that. How do you get an object for a specific user?

---

On a side note, I'm also new to node.js, so maybe there's just some giant similarity in node.js stuff that I'm not familliar with.

My code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
var kingdoms = [];
var ids = [];
const Kingdom = function(name, id){
    this.name = name;
    this.aa = 1;
    this.da = 1; 
    this.attackDate = 0;
    this.exhausaa = 0;
    ids.push(id);
};
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setGame("k^help");
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  console.log(msg);
  console.log(msg.content.trim().indexOf('k^addkingdom'));
  if (msg.content.trim() == 'k^help') {
    msg.channel.send({embed:
        {
            description: 'Note: All things in brackets must be replaced and are parameters.',
            fields: [{
                name: "k^help",
                value: "Displays this message."
            },
            {
                name: "k^addkingdom [name]",
                value: "Adds a kingdom to the database named [name]. One per person only."
            }]
        }
    });
  }
  if (msg.content.trim().indexOf('k^addkingdom ') == 0) {
    //if(ids.contains(msg.GuildMember.id)){
    //  msg.reply("You already have a kingdom!");
    //}
    var content = msg.content;
    content = content.replace('k^addkingdom ', '');
    content.trim();
    msg.reply("Kingdom " + content + " added!");
    kingdoms.push(new Kingdom(content/*, msg.GuildMember.id*/));
  }
});

client.login('Hidden for privacy');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are responding to a message, then you can get the user object by `msg.author`. And the user id by `msg.author.id`.
However if what you search is to get the user object from it's id, like when you have that saved in a database. Then you do it by that `client.users.get(id);`, where client is the discord client object.
Example if you want to send a message to a user in PM (private mode), then you do it this way

```
let user = client.users.get(id);
user.send("You need to wake up my friend!");
```

Another example responding to a message:

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
   if(msg.content === '!test') {
       let userId = msg.author.id;
       msg.author.send('hello i\'m here ! Your user Id is ' + userId);
       // let user = msg.author; user.send(...
   }
});
```

Another example when sending a message to a new server member at it's first arriving:

```
client.on("serverNewMember", (server, user) => {
     user.send("Welcome to: " + server.name);
});
```

Same example but using sendMessage (a bonus ^ ^):

```
client.on("serverNewMember", (server, user) => {
     client.sendMessage(user, "Welcome to: " + server.name);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

To get a specific user on a bot account, use `client.fetchUser(id)`. This will return a Discord user object.
Otherwise (as on selfbots), and on a channel, use channel object.member([userResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable)).